# Unexpected PHP behaviour in isset and empty

Tags: php

```
array(4) { ["id"]=>  int(0) ["pass"]=>  string(0) "" ["log_in"]=>  string(3) "no"  }
```

The problem in `id` when using `isset` it return `true` because it's `0`. When using empty I think it's doing the same. What is the best function to know whether it's set or not?

Comment: maybe if(!empty($array["id"]){ echo "array ID is set"; }, i think empty return false if 0 as an integer is set

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`empty` returns false for these:

- `""` (an empty string)
- `0` (0 as an integer)
- `"0"` (0 as a string)
- `NULL`
- `FALSE`
- `array()` (an empty array)
- `var $var` (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)

You need to use `isset` instead to check if it is there.

See this article on [empty vs isset](http://zainal.wordpress.com/2006/04/25/8/) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

```
if($array['id'] === 0) {
  true
} ?
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this chart on the PHP site](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

Answer (score 1):

a simple if condition will do for you

```
if(id)
{
}
```

try it if it works.

Comment: then do like this
if((isset($_SESSION['id']) && !empty($_SESSION['id']))

this should work

Answer (score 1):

if id is a database id is positive integer

so `if($id>0)` is one simple solution

OR

```
preg_match('#^[0-9]*$#', $id)
```

another